Are any existing or proposed inflatiable habitat designs designed in such a way that they can be deflated?
This question will shorter than this website usually likes, but I had to ask it.
There have, to my knowledge, been at least one or two inflatable space habitat modules built, and more proposed, but what is never made clear when information about these is presented is weather they can be deflated without damaging them.
Can inflatable habitat modules, existing or proposed, realistically be deflated without damaging them? If so, can they then be re-inflated?

Interesting question. I'm sure the initial deflating and packing for launch is an intricate process, difficult to duplicate in space. Deflating structures for tight packing often involves vacuum. Easy to do on the ground, but not viable in space. How would you squish it back into the delivery container?

I don't think so, If memory serves there are chemical changes involved when the unit is inflated. But I am not certain hence just a comment.
